# How to iterate through a list in a view using RazorEngine?

Tags: c#, razorengine

I'm using `RazorEngine` to render views within a WebApi project. I have the following code to iterate through a list of items:

```
@using System.Collections.Generic;

@using MyApp;

@Model IEnumerable<Customer>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            item.Name
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

However, I get an exception:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'RazorEngine.Compilation.RazorDynamicObject' to 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

What is the correct way to iterate through a list using `RazorEngine`?

Comment: What is the model type declared as? Why did you tag this as Web API when that appears completely unrelated to your question?

Comment: @mason Edited my question to reflect this.

Comment: Shouldn't the `@Model` directive be lower case?

Comment: What type of object goes into the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
@Model IEnumerable<Customer>
```

to

```
@model IEnumerable<Customer>
```

It's case sensitive, when declaring the model type you should use lower case. Then you should be able to correctly iterate over your model.

Also, you should change `item.Name` to be `@item.Name` since you are referring to a variable and don't just want a literal string.

I created an MCVE with RazorEngine 3.9.0 to verify that it worked for me.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using RazorEngine;

namespace MyApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var template = @"
@using System.Collections.Generic;
@using MyApp;
@model IEnumerable<Customer>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @item.Name
        </td>
    </tr>
}
";

            var result = Razor.Parse(template, new List<Customer>
                        { new Customer { Name = "Hello World" } });
            Console.WriteLine(result);
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public class Customer
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: When using '@model', I get : The name `model` does not exist in the current context.

Comment: @Ivan-MarkDebono It worked for me, see the example I edited into my answer.

Comment: @Ivan-MarkDebono, which version of `RazorEngine` are you using?

Comment: @Ivan-MarkDebono You accepted, what fixed your issue with "The name model does not exist in the current context"?

Comment: @Ivan-MarkDebono I think that is a bug in some versions of Visual Studio. I also get that error in my cshtml views.